# how to convert xv6 book to html with pictures saved

Tags: pandoc, html, htlatex

the book is here: https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv-book/

after `make`, it will generate book.tex, book.pdf and some other tex files. book.pdf have all pictures.

I have tried to `pandoc book.tex -o book.html` or `htlatex book.tex`, the HTML file I get is fine, but have no images inside. What should I do?

Comment: Without knowing pandoc: does it provide options, which control including or excluding graphics? // There are seveal packages available to convert .tex to .html. Though this is a controversial topic, you may have a look at these packages: https://ctan.org/topic/cvt-html .

Comment: Try make4ht instead of htlatex, it is it's successor. Images are supported, but there may be issues caused by package clashes

Comment: @michal.h21 Sorry, I forget to mention I have tried make4ht, but it still don'twork

Comment: I   see that images are in pdf, so therr can be a problem with conversion.

Comment: I've tried to compile the project and it seems that images are converted without problems. I only recommend to use the `ebb -x fig/*.pdf`. it will create files that TeX4ht needs for correct image dimension setting.

Comment: @michal.h21 Thanks, i will try ebb later